# $ rails -T & $ rails server (puma) is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a rails 5.2.0 set up on my macos catalina with rbenv 1.1.2/ruby 2.5.1. At the root of my app I get the following error:

```
$ rails -T
rails aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _ffi_type_double
  Referenced from: /Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle - /Users/sa/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/Users/sa/Projects/ror/bubblin.io/bubblin.io/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/Projects/ror/bubblin.io/bubblin.io/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/ffi_c
/Users/sa/Projects/ror/bubblin.io/bubblin.io/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sa/Projects/ror/bubblin.io/bubblin.io/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan:

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I can provide the full trace but just to know I reinstalled everything from scratch and my xcode-command-line tools/gcc are up-to-date. Is this something that has come up/been solved before?

Comment: besides botsnap error it showing ffi did you check this solution https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/687

Comment: I did rotate through these threads on Github. Guess each one is having their own solution to this problem and it depends on OS, system rubies and other environment/deployment configs. For me nothing has worked so far.

Comment: did you tried any other version of ruby/rails to install with rbenv?

Comment: i did. the issue persists with rails 6.0.2/ruby 2.6.5 as well. i also tried MacOS Mojave instead of Catalina to see if downgrade would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a week with this issue, I was forced to uninstall rbenv and purge all rubies under rbenv from my machine. I am now using the system rubies instead. My macbook pro has ruby 2.6.5 by default, so I bumped up the `.ruby-version` on my app from 2.5.1 to 2.6.7 to make sure i was on a development environment that “worked.”

Comment: Have a look at this guide:
https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

You may also find the ruby-build wiki useful:
https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment